# Generate Unsorted Unique Data C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have vector code in C++ like below:

```
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
       vec.push_back(i);
    }
```

Now, the values in vec are in sorted order in the range [0,9999] and are unique. How can i generate the same unique data in the range [0,9999] in an unsorted fashion.

Kindly help me please.

Comment: use std::shuffle or std::random_shuffle?

Comment: you probably should be more specific what 'unsorted' means. For example if they are in reverse order, does it mean 'unsorted'? 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5 ... is it 'unsorted'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Array Shuffle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922256/c-array-shuffle)

Comment: @simonzack  what's the problem with u if there is a duplicate?.. We are posting it just because we want a clear answer

Comment: @SowmiaMurthy I have no problem with you. Your question is a duplicate, therefore I marked it as one. Please search the site next time in order to avoid posting duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do is use [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
   vec.push_back(i);
}

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end(), g);
```

Comment: That looks like C++11 or C++14. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it with C++03?

Comment: @jww Yes, the above code is in c++ 11, I guess you can utilize Boost random_shuffle libraries to do the same thing in c++ 03

Comment: No need for boost `std::random_shuffle()` is in C++98

Comment: @Galik but mt19937 is not

Comment: But `mt19937` is not required by `std::random_shuffle()`. It may be a nice random generator but it is not essential to the task.

Comment: @taocp Any idea wat's the library in boost for including random_shuffle?

Comment: @SowmiaMurthy http://sureshamrita.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/random_shuffle-boost-generator/

Comment: @SowmiaMurthy: You don't need Boost, just use `std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());`. It's been in the standard library for ages.

Comment: @Blastfurnace And it has been deprecated in `C++14` in favor of `std::shuffle` since it calls `std::rand` which is considered harmful.

Comment: @pmr: I agree with you. I was responding specifically to their asking about Boost requirements and `random_shuffle`.

Comment: Its kind of ironic that `std::random_shuffle()` is less random than `std::shuffle()` ;o)

Answer (score 6):

A pre C++11 way to do this using the standard libraries is:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
   vec.push_back(i);
}

//http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

C++11/14 has much better random number generators though and `std::shuffle()` should be used in preference.

Answer (score 2):

A more "funny" way to do that is creating a linear congruential generator (LCG) in your loop to obtain random values.

```
 /**
  * Linear congruent generator for unrepeated values
  * x = ( a * x + b ) % M
  * a = 1103515245
  * b = 12345
  * M = 10000
  */

 for(int i = 0, int x = 0; vec.size != 10000 ; x = (x * 1103515245 + 12345) % 10000) {
    if(std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x) != vec.end()) {
        /* vec contains x, do nothing */
    } else {
        /* vec does not contain x */
        vec.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

The challenge is choose good a,b,M parameters to obtain more randomness in your sequence.

**Note**
This is a not production ready code. If you are looking for a copy/paste solution, please read another answers.

Comment: I dont think this will necessarily produce 10000 values in vec (due to collision which you correctly check for in the else clause).  You could do the same thing with rand() % 10000 ?

Comment: I cringe when I see *linear congruential generator*, but the OP asked for unique and not random...

Comment: Shure guys, is only "another" way to do the OP question.

Comment: @skimon, Thanks about the first. And about rand % 10000, how do you think that rand() was written?. I think that maybe with a a LCG.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can be a painfully slow solution. It would be better to implement your own Fisher–Yates shuffle if the standard library wasn't allowed.

Comment: You could add an explicit warning that this should never be used in a serious code! Some novice is bound to stumble upon it, and think it's a fine solution, since it is at SO...

Comment: @hyde, done. Thanks for remember me warning to copy pasters. Regards