# how can i shuffle an array of a given size and compare it with another array of same size in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

suppose I have an array A={212,323,234,567,545,765} and now I want shuffle this array so that the values are arranged randomly

like after shuffling it can be A={234,765,212,545,323,567}

I am not getting any clue how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: Copy the array into `B` then use `rand` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) to calculate a new index and copy the value from `B[index]`  to `A[newIndex]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Array Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922256/c-array-shuffle)

Answer (score 3):

Check [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal). There are some examples in documentation that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For basic shuffling you'd want to use [std::shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/shuffle).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Create mersenne twister RNG
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    // Initialize Array A
    std::array<int, 6u> A{ 212,323,234,567,545,765 };
    // Print A
    std::copy(A.begin(), A.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    // Shuffle A
    std::shuffle(A.begin(), A.end(), g);
    // Print A
    std::copy(A.begin(), A.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```